# Test Automation ZAP & E2E (Cypress)

Tags: docker, automated-tests, gitlab, gitlab-ci, zap

in the end I managed to achieve my goal with **e2e** and **ZAP** (using Docker).

So, I able to see the results from *http://localhost:8091/OTHER/core/other/htmlreport* or from the terminal of my local pc (using curl -X GET)

Enviroment:

- GitLab Repository with **e2e** tests, run with Cypress (linux image)
- Docker image with **ZAP** (latest version)

For the moment I'm thinking about using ZAP as a service in the yml file. 
This means, i will also have to update the package.json file and the dockerfile, in order to divert traffic here from **Cypress** container, and run ZAP.

- **Cypress**: forwarding the traffic (via proxy) to ZAP (option *HTTP_PROXY = http://containerAlias_port*)
- **ZAP Daemon**: listening at localhost to receive the data from e2e (also using port binding)

Example of gitlab-ci.yml:

```
services:
 - name: owasp/zap2docker-stable:latest
   alias: zap
   ports:
       - "8092:8092"
   entrypoint: ["zap.sh", "-daemon", "-port", "8092", "-host", "0.0.0.0", "-config", "api.disablekey=true", "-config", "api.addrs.addr.name=.*", "-config", "api.addrs.addr.regex=true"]
```

The problems are:

1) How to get results from the Daemon in such environment? Because the "terminal" with CURL is not so suitable for CI/CD

2) The main problem is how to get results. Using the terminal locally is not a very "automated" solution, and I would like to have the opportunity to **save a report file** (html or json).
I tried with the Baseline Scan but I have big problems targeting the ip address where the tests are performed.
Are there other possible solutions? Maybe even with Daemon to get around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The approach mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Docker#accessing-the-api-from-outside-of-the-docker-container) works for me:

Run ZAP as a daemon listening on `"0.0.0.0"`:

```
docker run -p 8090:8090 -i owasp/zap2docker-stable zap.sh -daemon -port 8090 -host 0.0.0.0
```

Find out the container id:

```
docker ps
```

Find out which address has been assigned to it:

```
docker inspect <CONTAINER ID> | grep IPAddress
```

You should be then able to point your browser at the specified host/port and access the ZAP API, eg `http://172.17.0.8:8090/`

Then, I use the following url to view the report & to publish in jenkins using the [htmlpublisher](https://plugins.jenkins.io/htmlpublisher/) plugin. You can use also curl/wget to download it:

```
http://172.17.0.8:8090/OTHER/core/other/htmlreport/?
```

Comment: Hi Amit, i already checked it in the documentation, and it helped me to get to this point. As you can understand, this solution is not so suitable to implement automation. The goal, is to be able to perform sec-scans in the Gitlab directory. So i'm trying to understand if the Daemon could give me results/reports without using "curl" or any other option from my localhost. But thank you for your answer, i will investigate the htmlpublisher ;)